# If I accelerate through space, can I say all stars gain kinetic energy?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, reference-frames, acceleration, relative-motion

Suppose I accelerate through empty space. Say all stars are small heavy marbles I can use to do work with by means of their velocity. Say I can let them smash into some generator that turns their motion in electricity.

Will the maximum energy I can gain be just my own kinetic energy wrt to these marbles? If so, does it make sense for me to say that there is a huge amount of kinetic energy residing in the marbles?

Let me make myself clearer, as some people don't seem to get what I mean.  An accelerated frame in empty space is equivalent to a non-moving frame in a gravity field. On Earth I can gather all marbles that fall down on Earth and turn their motion into electricity, if I want. This can't be done, obviously, in an accelerated frame. Maybe if an Earth-sized object accelerated along. Which would cost more energy than I would gain from collecting the marbles. So, even if all marbles have kinetic energy in my frame, accelerating through space, I can't collect it. Then in what sense they have kinetic energy?

Comment: *"Say I can let them smash into some generator that turns their motion in electricity."* What is this supposed to mean? Generators are not magic things that "turn motion in electricity", they have an actual principle of operation. We cannot magically extract kinetic energy from things that pass us by.

Comment: I don't see why this was closed for being unclear.  Suppose the accelerating "space ship" carries a wheel like a water wheel.  Marbles hit the wheel, it spins, and you can mill wheat or whatever you need energy for. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I don’t think that last paragraph says anything that was misunderstood by either answer. You may have misunderstood the answers

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, the idea of equivalence b/w accelerating frame and freely falling frame is only true locally. It means that if you monitor the motion of marbles in a small enough region of space time , the KE of marbles powered by acceleration will be indistinguishable from KE powered by gravitational field. In both cases, marbles possess KE . There is no change in reference frame like the way you have described. You have misinterpreted the equivalence b/w this two cases and this has created the confusion

Comment: It's illogical to assume that by applying a force to yourself, all other objects in the universe gain kinetic energy.  Such an assumption definitely violates the law of conservation of energy, and it also violates any notion of causality.

Comment: @DavidWhite But how do we know who actually accelerated. Accelerating all stars in one direction has the same effect as me accelerating.

Comment: @DavidWhite No, it won't... You are right. You create more energy.

Comment: @KP99 Can't we say the accelerating spaceship in empty space is equivalent to a uniform gravity field (say of an infinite massive plane  to which the marbles fall?

Comment: @Felicia Yes, but it is only true locally. Actually it is true approximately. Since we are considering some non-zero gravitational field, this will correspond to presence of some intrinsic curvature. It turns out that you can construct various curvature invariants which won't vanish locally in any coordinate system. In this way you can actually distinguish spaceship accelerating in empty space-time with motion in gravity field

Comment: @KP99 So there is a difference between standing on an infinite massive plate and accelerating in empty space?

Comment: True, but just by looking at the motion of spaceship locally, you can't make any difference between gravitational field and acceleration. By "locally", I mean only a small neighborhood of a point. This neighborhood is so small that for first order correction , the parallel transport of a vector along a closed loop in this region produces zero deviation, i.e. curvature is zero. In order to measure curvature you have to take a large neighborhood

Comment: @KP99 So in a uniform field, say of an infinite massive plane, there is a second order contribution, while there isn't if you measure this in an accelerated frame?

Answer (score 6):

No.  You don't get to change the frame of reference you are using for consideration as a way to create energy.  It doesn't work anyway.

Just because some object has a lot of KE in one frame doesn't mean that the energy is available.  In order to extract it you have to interact with it somehow (in this case, that is your generator that they smash into.

It is only the relative motion between the marbles and the generator that matters.  By modifying your frame of reference, you change the KE of both, but you do not change the relative velocity.

Imagine watching a car crash from an airliner.  The car appears to be driving 500mph!  But when it crashes, it only slows to 480mph.  The energy released from that deceleration is small.

Comment: Indeed. In a plane the Earth has a lot of kinetic energy. But how to use it...?

Comment: If you have some KE distributed among some objects, the most you can extract is to bring all of them to rest in the frame where their center of mass is at rest.     The speed of some object that can't interact with them doesn't matter.

Comment: Because energy goes squared with velocity, 500 -> 480 is still a large difference. The generator can still only extract from the equivalent of 20 mph though - the rest goes to accelerating the generator itself.

Answer (score 5):

> Will the maximum energy I can gain be just my own kinetic energy wrt to these marbles?

No, your own KE will not be the limit.

The marbles can exchange momentum and energy, and energy can change forms between kinetic and other forms of energy. The minimum KE will be achieved when all of the marbles are at rest with respect to the center of momentum. The amount of energy thus converted from KE to other forms will not generally have anything to do with your own KE.

> If so, does it make sense for me to say that there is a huge amount of kinetic energy residing in the marbles?

Yes. Whether the energy can be extracted or not is not particularly relevant. In the reference frame you describe there is a potential energy, and for conservation of energy the potential energy lost by the marbles must be balanced by kinetic energy gained. You cannot dismiss the KE without breaking the conservation of energy in that frame.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question, in that it hinges on what you mean by the word 'gain'.

Suppose you and a trillion 1kg marbles are all at rest relative to each other. Your collective KE is zero.

If you start moving at 10 metres per second, the KE of the marbles in your new frame is 50,000,000,000,000 joules, so you might conclude they had 'gained' extra KE.

However, the marbles have not gained that KE as a consequence of your acceleration. Before you started to move, the marbles already had a KE of 50,000,000,000,000 joules in that frame.

The point is that KE is frame dependent, so you can make the KE of the marbles take any value by picking some reference frame to quantify it in.

In that sense, the value of the KE is meaningless. To transfer the KE of the marbles (ie to use it to do work), the marbles need to interact with something. Suppose that when you accelerated to 10m/s you were carrying a generator that consisted of something like a waterwheel, so that as the marbles passed you they collided with the paddles and caused the wheel to turn. Each collision with a marble will slow you somewhat, so that after a number of collisions you will eventually end up at rest with the marbles again (ie in the frame in which they have zero KE).

By conservation of energy, the maximum energy you could extract from your marble-wheel generator would be equal to the energy you had expended in accelerating it and you to 10m/s.

Comment: The last statement in your answer is what I wrote in my question: "Will the maximum energy I can gain be just my own kinetic energy wrt to these marbles?" Is your answer at odds with the answer of Dale?

Comment: I don't think so, Felicia, because in my answer I supposed the marbles were at rest relative to each other, whereas Dale didn't.

Comment: Doesn't relativity say that all motion is relative Acceleration is òf course absolute, but how do you know you accelerate in empty space or in a uniform gravity field?